# Сортировка параметров группировки в Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Есть БД с данными, таблица, в которой 2 столбца - UserId, CandidatId. Задача - получить количество User-ов с Number 1, 2, n и вывести в формате Json. Уже имею решение

```
var choises = from voter in voters
                      group voter by voter.CandidatId into g
                      select new { Id = g.Key, count = g.Count() };
```

но проблема в том, что Number-s сортируются в порядке увеличения, а именно

```
[{"Id":4,"count":35},{"Id":1,"count":36},{"Id":5,"count":40},{"Id":3,"count":43},{"Id":2,"count":50}]
```

Вопрос: Как произвести сортировку Id, что бы результат был критерий сортировки был не count, а Id?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `order by Id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите с помощью [orderby](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/orderby-clause) то, что вам необходимо.

Например:

```
var choises = from voter in voters
    orderby voter.CandidatId
    group voter by voter.CandidatId into g
    select new { Id = g.Key, count = g.Count() };
```

Либо сортируйте уже группу:

```
var choises = from voter in voters
    group voter by voter.CandidatId into g
    orderby g.Key
    select new { Id = g.Key, count = g.Count() };
```

Здесь уже смотрите сами что именно вы хотите и как именно хотите этого достичь.

---

Вообще лично я не люблю такой вид LINQ, ведь проще и понятней написать что то вроде:

```
var choises = voters.GroupBy(x => x.CandidatId)
    .Select(x => new {Id = x.Key, count = x.Count()});
```

Ну и сортировка также просто добавляется, к примеру, в самый конец `.OrderBy(x => x.Id)`.
Так что смотрите, может и вам будет этот способ удобней...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, написал такое же решение: var result = voters.GroupBy(p => p.Id, p => p.CandidatId, (key, g) => new { Id = key, CandidatId = g.ToList() }).OrderBy(p=>p.CandidatId); но после прогона через Foreach ругается на не реализованный интерфейс IComporable

Comment: Разобрался, больше спасибо.